# AUCTeX installation failure "Error occurred processing /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/debian-startup.el"

Tags: linux, debian, emacs, latex, auctex

I started to work with Debian Testing on a new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd gen.). I installed Emacs and AUCTeX the 'usual way': `sudo apt-get install emacs24 auctex`. My `.emacs` contains (for many years, under Ubuntu):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp")
(require 'tex-site)
```

When I start emacs, I obtained an error saying that `tex-site.el` could not be found. I then looked up `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp` (and also the corresponding path with emacs replaced by emacs24... I never know which is the "correct" one) but these folders were empty. I thought something went wrong during the installation and wanted to start from scratch by using `sudo apt-get purge...`, but I obtained:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge emacs24 emacs24-bin-common emacs24-common emacsen-common auctex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 : Depends: libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I'm wondering a bit about the `Some packages could not be installed...` since I tried to *remove* them (I also used `sudo apt-get remove...`). 
But then if I try to re-install, I obtain:

```
$ sudo apt-get install emacs24 auctex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
auctex is already the newest version.
emacs24 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up auctex (11.87-3+deb8u1) ...
Install emacsen-common for emacs24
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs24
Wrote /etc/emacs24/site-start.d/00debian-vars.elc
>>Error occurred processing /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/debian-startup.el: File error (("Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/debian-startup.el"))
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
dpkg: error processing package auctex (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 auctex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can this be solved? Shall I remove emacs related folders by hand and then try again? I know this is a hack and I probably shouldn't have used `purge` that early, but this is the situation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacsen-common/+bug/1311985) and adapted the workaround to `sudo rm /var/lib/emacsen-common/state/flavor/installed/emacs24`. Then `sudo apt-get install emacs24 auctex` worked.